# A library is missing with the DOM - React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom

I'm using a jquery library to change the scroll bar (`malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin`),
The problem is, In my React code when I try to show a `Grid` based on a condition:

```
{isTrue?
<Grid xs={12}/> : null
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

I know that the library I'm using is missing with the DOM
PS: when I don't use the library, my code works fine.

Is there a way to solve this problem where all works fine?

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery with React. They're two different libraries with two very different ways of updating the DOM.

Comment: @Andy I have no choice, because there is no customizable scrollbars with React...

Comment: You really cannot have two incompatible libraries working together. You said yourself that your code works if you don't include jQuery. [This might help though](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/586). But it's a work-around, not a decent solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already did what is mentionned in the post, they just tell how to configure the library with react...